# How can i connect a iphone to another iphone or ipad programically and transfer data using Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, offline-mode

I am in the scenario to send my local database's data across different devices (iPhone or iPad) using Objective-C. Is this possible to transfer the raw data between iPads/iPhones? Since My app should work in offline mode. I would be really appreciated if someone could assist me in the correct way to do this, if possible could anyone share me sample code to get started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is quite broad. Refer to the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide and then ask *specific* questions where you have difficulty

Comment: I just wanted to know the possibilities to work with bluetooth. would my scenario work to transfer the data (not a file ) between the devices?

Comment: If your app's deployment target is iOS 7.0 or newer, you could look into [**Multipeer Connectivity Framework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html).

Comment: Everything is just data, just a collection of bytes.  Core Bluetooth lets you transfer bytes.  It doesn't, in fact, allow you to transfer files, except as a number of 20 byte packets